# Generate arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Is there any way i can generate all these arrays using int value? ... I dont want to copy/paste so much as in my next view controller i'll have about 86 arrays.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

```
NSPredicate *parentPredicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings)
{
    return [evaluatedObject[@"parent_id"] isEqual:@"1"]; 
}];
NSPredicate *parentPredicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings)
{
    return [evaluatedObject[@"parent_id"] isEqual:@"2"];
}];
NSPredicate *parentPredicate3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings)
{
    return [evaluatedObject[@"parent_id"] isEqual:@"3"];
}];
NSPredicate *parentPredicate4 = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings)
{
    return [evaluatedObject[@"parent_id"] isEqual:@"4"];
}];
NSPredicate *parentPredicate5 = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings)
{
    return [evaluatedObject[@"parent_id"] isEqual:@"5"];
}];
NSPredicate *parentPredicate6 = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings)
{
    return [evaluatedObject[@"parent_id"] isEqual:@"6"];
}];
NSPredicate *parentPredicate7 = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings)
{
    return [evaluatedObject[@"parent_id"] isEqual:@"7"];
}];
NSPredicate *parentPredicate8 = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings)
{
    return [evaluatedObject[@"parent_id"] isEqual:@"8"];
}];
NSPredicate *parentPredicate9 = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings)
{
    return [evaluatedObject[@"parent_id"] isEqual:@"9"];
}];

childID_1 = [parentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:parentPredicate1];
childID_2 = [parentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:parentPredicate2];
childID_3 = [parentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:parentPredicate3];
childID_4 = [parentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:parentPredicate4];
childID_5 = [parentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:parentPredicate5];
childID_6 = [parentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:parentPredicate6];
childID_7 = [parentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:parentPredicate7];
childID_8 = [parentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:parentPredicate8];
childID_9 = [parentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:parentPredicate9];

_allArrays = [[ NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:childID_1, childID_2, childID_3, childID_4, childID_5, childID_6, childID_7, childID_8, childID_9, nil];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop

```
NSMutableArray *childObjects = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < N; i++)
{
    NSPredicate *parentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        NSString *value = [@(i) stringValue];
        return [evaluatedObject[@"parent_id"] isEqual:value];
    }];

    [childObjects addObject:[parentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:parentPredicate]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

block can use local variable so you can put them into a loop

```
_allArrays = [[ NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

    NSPredicate *parentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, 
    NSDictionary *bindings)
    {
        return [evaluatedObject[@"parent_id"] isEqual:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]]; 
    }];
    [_allArrays addObject:[[parentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:parentPredicate]]];
}
```

Comment: But if i already have a categoryInt how can i use its values?

Comment: @AlexandruAron what is `categoryInt`??